# Meteor accounts-entry package, extrasignupfield, how to add a dropdown list?

Tags: meteor

I am using the accounts-entry package in my Meteor application, and would like to add a dropdown selector to the registration page as an extra sign up field. So for example, when registering, people would enter the following:

```
username: johndoe
email: john@doe.com
password: somepassword
country: (here they would select one of Canada, US, etc.)
preferred day to participate: (select one of Monday, Tues, etc.)
```

I think that the package does not support this by default.

How can this package be modified to support this feature?

Or which other packages already have this feature? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using the `useraccounts` packages. You can add extra signup fields with it. I don't remember if it will allow you to add dropdowns to signup, but you can definitely do a lot more with it than you can with `accounts-entry`.

Here's the link for `useraccounts:boostrap`: https://atmospherejs.com/useraccounts/bootstrap

But there are many more packages by the same author that can help you if you don't want to use bootstrap.